# MVC3 jQuery Autocomplete is not displaying the results

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The following jQuery autocomplete code is not displaying the results in MVC3.  When I debug the code, I can see it is calling the QuickSearchByLastName correctly.  Can someone tell me if my code is incorrect?  (I also tried with jquery-1.6.2.min.js with no luck)  Thank you!

Index.cshtml:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "results"
}
))
{               
    <input type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("QuickSearchByLastName","Search")"  />                 
}
<div id="results" >
</div>    


----------------------------------------------------------------
Search Controller:

    public ActionResult QuickSearchByLastName(string term)
            {
                using (var context = new CSCContext())
                {
                    var searchResults = context.Students
                                      .Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(term) && s.IsActive == true)
                                      .Take(10)
                                      .Select(s => new { label = s.LastName });


                    return Json(searchResults, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }                
            }
```

---

```
_Layout.cshtml:
    @Content.Script("jquery-1.4.4.min.js", Url)              
    @Content.Script("jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js", Url)
    @Content.Script("jquery-ui.min.js", Url)     
    @Content.Script("jquery.validate.min.js", Url)    
    @Content.Script("jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js", Url)    
    @Content.Script("CSC.js", Url)  
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
```

---

CSC.js

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () 
    {
        $(this).autocomplete({ 
                               source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete")
                              }
                            );
    });

});
```

The following code fixed the issue:

```
public ActionResult QuickSearchByLastName(string term)
        {           
            var context = new CSCContext();
            try
            {

                var searchResults = context.Students
                                  .Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(term) && s.IsActive == true)
                                  .Take(10)
                                  .Select(s => new { label = s.LastName });


                return Json(searchResults.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }                       
        }
```

Comment: The plugin or the 1.8 ui feature?

Comment: You can indeed use json for the autocomplete plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried replicating your scenario to no avail as it always worked for me. Here's what I did.

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the Internet Template
2. HomeController:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }

       public ActionResult QuickSearchByLastName(string term)
       {
           var results = Enumerable
               .Range(1, 5)
               .Select(x => new { 
                   id = x, 
                   label = "label " + x, 
                   value = "value " + x 
               });
           return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Index.cshtml

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
           $(':input[data-autocomplete]').each(function () {
               $(this).autocomplete({
                   source: $(this).attr('data-autocomplete')
               });
           });
       });
   </script>

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {               
       <input type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("QuickSearchByLastName", "Home")" />
   }
   ```

I used `jquery-1.5.1.min.js` and `jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js` which are bundled by default with ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM. I also tried putting this in a `Ajax.BeginForm` and also importing the default unobtrusive scripts and it was still working for me.

Comment: Do you think it could be an issue with IE8 configuration?

Comment: @rk1962, did you try my code to rule this possibility out? In a brand new project? If it works then the problem is not in IE8. If it doesn't we shall see (but I would be surprised).

Comment: I just tried your code and it is working fine.  So, it is not IE8 issue.

Comment: I have figured it out.  I have removed "using" from the controller method and it is working now.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @rk1962, you could also call `searchResults.ToList()` to force the execution of the query while inside the context.

Comment: Yes, it also worked when I just called searchResult.Toarry() i.e. return Json(SearchResults.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: @rk1962, this code is not correct as you are no longer disposing the context. Use `.ToList()` instead when calling the Json result.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1553/discussion-between-rk1962-and-darin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the script file

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

needs to be included in the top, NOT as specified in the bottom of any file to increase performance.

If you do it will work.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer :** Refer this post [jQuery UI autocomplete with ASP.NET Web API](http://yassershaikh.com/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-asp-net-web-api/)

**Long answer :**

**Step 1 : Getting Web Api Ready**

Lets first create a **web api method** that will return a list of item (Artists) using the search term **query** sent from the autocomplete textbox. In this post I am not using database, instead I'll be using List to keep this example as simple as possible.

Below is how I have defined my Artist class

```
public class Artist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

Next I have created a **Web Api GET method** that will use the search term entered in the autocomplete textbox and with a little help of LINQ will return a list of matching results.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Autocomplete.Controllers
{
    public class ArtistApiController : ApiController
    {

        public List<Artist> ArtistList = new List<Artist>
        {
            new Artist{Id = 1, Name = "Sonu Nigam"},
            new Artist{Id = 2, Name = "Sunidhi Chauhan"},
            new Artist{Id = 3, Name = "Shreya Goshal"},
            new Artist{Id = 4, Name = "Mohit Chauhan"},
            new Artist{Id = 5, Name = "Nihkil Dsouza"},
            new Artist{Id = 6, Name = "Kailash Kher"},
            new Artist{Id = 7, Name = "Atif Aslam"},
            new Artist{Id = 8, Name = "Ali Zafar"},
            new Artist{Id = 9, Name = "Shafaqat Ali"},
            new Artist{Id = 10, Name = "Shankar Madahevan"}
        }; 


        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<Artist> Get(string query)
        {
            return ArtistList.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(query)).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Our server side code is ready ! Time to test it out.

[image]

**Step 2 : Client side code**

Include jquery-ui.js and jquery.ui.css in your html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" ></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="body">
    <label for="autocomplete-textbox">Search : </label>
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete-textbox" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#autocomplete-textbox').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        // prepare url : for example '/api/artistapi?query=sonu
        var autocompleteUrl = '/api/artistapi' + '?query=' + request.term;
        $.ajax({
            url: autocompleteUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                // call autocomplete callback method with results  
                response($.map(json, function (data, id) {
                    return {
                        label: data.Name,
                        value: data.Id
                    };
                }));
            },
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('some error occured', textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        alert('you have selected ' + ui.item.label + ' ID: ' + ui.item.value);
        $('#autocomplete-textbox').val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    }
});
});
</script>
```

One thing to note here is that inside the success method I have used the following code :

```
response($.map(json, function (data, id) {
    return {
        label: data.Name,
        value: data.Id
    };
}));
```

**data.Id** and **data.Name** is used because in the ajax response (as shown below) data is returned in this format.

[image]

**Step 3 : Test & Output :**

[image]

Taken from [here](http://yassershaikh.com/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-asp-net-web-api/)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as rk1962 (and a quick websearch shows plenty of other people having the same issue). I replicated Darin's code from above and it worked. It is when I take the script from the top of Index.cshtml and place it in a separate scripts file that it stops working - QuickSearchByLastName doesn't get called.

Andrew